# How does the military know about the egg?

Tags: under-the-dome

In season 1, episode 12, we hear a radio broadcast from outside the dome in which:

> The military says it is searching for an egg in a mini-dome, and that Barbie is their best bet for acquiring it.

**How does the military know about this?**

Comment: This is a pretty big spoiler for the *current* season, if you want it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The military seems to know an awful lot about what's going on beneath the dome. Similarly, Aktion (the private company / military contractor run by Barbie's father) seems to have a pretty good idea about the egg and it's uses.  Early on, it's not clear how they know these things. In the season 3, though, we find out something important:

> Aktion had people in Chester's Mill, looking for the egg, long before the dome came down. They had already found fragments of other eggs and were tracking them since they "landed" (presumably from space).

Exactly *how long* they've known what they know is an evolving element of the season 3 plot.